# Radiobuttonlist - Access Click/change using jquery and reading values (rbList values are bound using binding)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to access the value of the radio button option selected by the user.  The radio buttons in the radio button list are generated by binding using datasource

```
radioButtonList.DataSource = data;
radioButtonList.DataBind();
```

Now I want to check the value of the selected radio button and do something after. I can generate an alert message but i am not able to get the value of the selected radio button

```
$('#<%= rbDepartment.ClientID %>').change(function() {
    alert("working!");
  }).change();
```

Can someone show me how to ge the value of selected radio button.

Thanks,
Madhav

Comment: this is C# and asp.net correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var value = $("input[@name=GroupName]:checked").val();
```